# Pycharm not staying connected to GitHub

Tags: github, pycharm, ide

I'm running PyCharm community edition (latest) and having problems getting it to stay authorized to GitHub. About every 5 - 10 minutes I get a pop-up asking to authorize to GitHub with either sign-in (which I've done) or using a token. I had problems initially with the token so did the sign-in option which worked for a couple weeks, but now it's not holding the authorization. I've tried removing myself as a user from the VCS settings and re-adding, I've restarted PyCharm, even rebooted my Mac, but still getting this. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: This question is not related to a code problem/error. Please use the correct channels of communication from the product that are you mention like a forum or helpdesk.

Comment: @AliBriceño considering the 3rd point here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, I'm pretty sure this is very much an appropriate place to ask this question since IDE's themselves are widely used software tools.

Comment: You have absolutely right my friend. Please, ignore my comment. I hope you can get the help you need.

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out. Apparently I had put an expiration on my auth token (that I forgot about) and it had expired. Renewing the token in my GitHub security profile did the trick.